# Can't fetch selected row in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I have defined the following bootstrap table in my ASP.NET web page:

```
<table class="display table table-bordered" data-click-to-select="true" 
                    data-pagination="true" data-sortable="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-single-select="true" data-maintain-selected="true"
                    data-show-toggle="true" data-id-field="customer_id" id="customers" name="customers">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                            <th data-field="Customer_ID" data-sortable="true">Acct. #</th>
                            <th data-field="Company_Name" data-sortable="true">Company</th>
                            <th data-field="Federal_EIN" data-sortable="true">EIN</th>
                            <th data-field="City" data-sortable="true">City</th>
                            <th data-field="State" data-sortable="true">State</th>
                            <th data-field="Creation_Date" data-sortable="true">Added</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

And, following sample code on SO, I am trying to use the following jQuery/JavaScript code to fetch and display info from the selected row:

```
            $('#customers').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
                checkedRows.push({ id: row.id, name: row.name, forks: row.forks });
                console.log(checkedRows);
                $.each(checkedRows, function (index, value) {
                    $(console.log(value.id + " | " + value.name + " | " + value.forks));
                });
            });

            $('#customers').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
                $.each(checkedRows, function (index, value) {
                    if (value.id === row.id) {
                        checkedRows.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
                console.log(checkedRows);
            });
```

The problem is, the console shows the values of the checked row as `undefined`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `checkedRows`? That isn't defined anywhere. I think we need to see more of your code. Is this code fired before the element exists?

Comment: checkedRows is defined earlier in the code as ```var checkedRows = [];```.  Other than that, the only other code in the javascript is for the search functionality that loads the table.

Comment: You should have a look at  [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We really need some more information, since we don't know what the row data is. The more information we get, the more likely it is that we can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out that the issue is, the `row` object's fields are case-sensitive, based on the fields the table is populated with (although interestingly, the bootstrap table doesn't care if the `data-field` parameters observe case-sensitivity!).  So, once I used the proper case sensitivity in referring to the fields of the `row`, everything showed up.
Thank you everyone for your help!